# Printing words that only start with specific letter in Python

Tags: python, string

I just started learning Python. The question was this:

st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'

My answer was this:

```
space = ' '
before = space
indexCount = 0
for letter in st:
    if before == space and (letter == 's' or letter == 'S'):
        print(st[indexCount:st[indexCount:].find(' ')])
    before = letter
    indexCount += 1
```

As output it gives 2 lines and 'sentenc'

Now I know the correct code for this would be something like:

```
for word in st.split():
    if word[0] == 's':
        print(word)
```

But I don't understand what was wrong with my code. Why it doesn't print s or start?

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
space = ' '
before = space
indexCount = 0
for letter in st:
    if before == space and (letter == 's' or letter == 'S'):
        print(st[indexCount:st[indexCount:].find(' ')])
    before = letter
    indexCount += 1
```

Expected:
start
s
sentence

Resulted:

sentenc

Thanks everyone. I rewrote the code with the information I learned from you.

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
space = ' '
before = space
indexCount = 0
for letter in st:
    if before == space and (letter == 's' or letter == 'S'):
        if st[indexCount:].find(' ') == -1:
            endIndex = None
        else:
            endIndex = st[indexCount:].find(' ') + indexCount
        print(st[indexCount:endIndex])
    before = letter
    indexCount += 1
```

Learned the substring-string index difference and that find() gives -1 if it can't find the value that is given. Thanks again :).

Comment: Nice start :) people will probably suggest you look at `str.split()`, but I encourage you to also try and debug your current version, it will be beneficial to your learning

Answer (score 3):

When you are slicing a str in python the index will start from the starting given index and will end in the ending given index -1.

For example: `st[0:4]` will start with index 0 and end in index 3 therefore the output will be `prin`.
In order to fix that you will need to do +1 like this:

```
st[indexCount:st[indexCount:].find(' ') + 1]
```

Moreover, when you are running this line:

```
st[indexCount:].find(' ') + 1
```

Note that you are slicing the first `indexCount` amount of indexes!
For example:

The word `start` is at index 26.
When you are looking for the first space after the word `start` it will look in this str:

`start with s in this sentence`

which is a substring from the original str starting from index 26. When you are slicing an str it will create a new str also remember that in Python str is an immutable type!

So in order to fix that you will need to add the index that you already sliced, which will look like this:

```
st[indexCount:indexCount + st[indexCount:].find(' ') + 1]
```

Another issue that you will encounter is that the last word is not recognized and that is because there is no space after it. I suggest adding a space at the end of the sentence before checking it.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in your print statement.
More specifically in st[indexCount:].find(' '), which will return the index of the substring and not the index of the full sentence.

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
print(f"Your sentence: '{st}'")

indexCount = 26
print(f"Only part of sentence: '{st[indexCount:]}'")

print(f"Index: {st[indexCount:].find(' ')}")

> Your sentence: 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence' 
> Only part of sentence: 'start with s in this sentence'
> Index: 5
```

This can be fixed with for each word that is followed by a space, so it will still fail on the last word 'sentence'.

```
st[indexCount: st[indexCount:].find(' ') + indexCount]
```

Comment: Might want to add that to fix this, you can use `st[indexCount:indexCount + st[indexCount:].find(' ')]`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
print(st[indexCount:st[indexCount:].find(' ') + 1])
```

Comment: But that would just make it print the space too. I just need the words

Comment: You can add .strip() method at the end

Comment: Sorry forgot to say, it doesn't solve the problem. It just gives 3 lines as output

Comment: You can also use the "re" library to resolve this problem :)


`import re

s = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'

result = re.findall(r"(?<=\W)s[\w\d]+", s)

print(*result, sep="\n")`

Answer (score 0):

can be modified like this，st[indexCount:].find(' ') the index it gets is in st[indexCount:] not st.

```py
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
space = ' '
before = space
indexCount = 0
for letter in st:
    if before == space and (letter == 's' or letter == 'S'):
        print(st[indexCount:st[indexCount:].find(' ') + indexCount])
    before = letter
    indexCount += 1
```

output:

```py
start
s
```

There is a bug in this way, that is, it will not read the last `sentence`

Comment: not a bug, for last word there is no space after it so, str.find return -1 , this make list index make slicing as st[1: -1] , you need to check that and made a condition

Answer (score 0):

your code lack few cases where it wont recoginse, ie if only one word there and no space and if first word start with s. also regarding inbetween word start with s or S index provided in slice is issue.

here is a little updated version of your code

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
space = ' '

previous = None
index = 0

for char in st:
    if (previous is None or previous == space) and (char == 's' or char == 'S'):
        next_space_index = st[index+1: ].find(space)
        if next_space_index != -1:
            word = st[index: index+next_space_index+1]
        else:
            word = st[index:]
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the solution could be:

```py
for word in st.split():
    if word[0].lower() == 's':
        print(word)
```

Comment: but as I mentioned in my comment, for your learning it's more important to understand how to debug your own approach